# Creating boootstrap panels based on the value given in text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've a simple bootstrap text field for entering ticket quantity. When I enter ticket quantity as 2, then I want two bootstrap panels having a form created automatically. If the value is 3, then 3 bootstrap panels having a form are created automatically. How can I do it?
JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/gcxxehwf/
**`Html code:`**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="price">Ticket quantity:</label>
    <input type="number" name="tquantity" value="" class="form-control" id="tquantity">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12" id="participantpanel"></div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/gcxxehwf/1/

Comment: Not a perfect solution, when I decrease the ticket quantity, bootstrap panels should be adjusted automatcally

Comment: So Mr. @Ajay, Do you expect everything for free ? You have put __0__ efforts in your post...

Comment: @Rayon: Please check my jsfiddle link, I tried on my own and then asked in SO

Comment: It shows serious lack of research.. You have not attached any events to your DOM.. I have provided basic demo for your use-case...

Comment: Well, okay... thank you for that basic demo

Comment: what can be the maximum number? can it be more than 3 or n number ?

Comment: @Princesodhi: It is `n` number as of now

Answer (score 0):

By using AngularJS it would be much easier than with the jQuery append method. Just use the ng-repeat directive and repeat the panel as often the value is.

Comment: Yeah... But we need to take a simplistic approach as requested by client...